# Converting an approximate algorithm for the minimization to the maximization form

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I have a $\rho$-approximate algorithm for a minimization algorithm, where the objective is to minimize $O$ ($\rho \geq 1$ is some constant), such that the algorithm's solution is always within $\rho$ times the optimal. Is it possible to use this to get an approximate algorithm to maximize $-O$? What is the approximation ratio of this algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: Without any further restrictions, context or caveats, the answer is trivially yes.

Comment: @orlp So what is the approximation ratio for this maximization problem?

Comment: Am I missing something? Maximizing $-O$ is exactly the same as minimizing $O$ without any further changes, just negating the output.

Comment: @orlp Yes, but having a $\rho$ approximation ratio does not make sense for a maximization problem, since for maximization the ratio should not be more than 1. But the ratio does not seem to be $1/\rho$ either. So I am confused about what the approximation ratio of the maximization version is.